Name of movie or show with female sword fighter in dystopian future or perhaps another planet?
I can't give too many details as I was only flipping through channels and don't know the story line and my memory is horrible. I am guessing it was possibly on the SyFy channel in the early 2000's or older but it's only a guess. The scene I remember was the female hero was fighting a much bigger and stronger guy. In fact his blade cut through a metal table or anything else that was getting in the way. All of a sudden both fighters stopped. You could see his eyes looking back and fourth just standing still. She says something like "feeling better?" or perhaps it was something else. Then his head rolls off because apparently she decapitated him in battle despite that he managed to stand that way for a short time. This movie also had another male character that had a removable head so the creators must have liked that idea.

Ultraviolet perhaps, though I don't recall that scene

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DiagonalCut might have some references for the "sudden realization of decapitation"
